# How to convert strings of 2D array into each char array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am taking inputs in 2D-Array. i.e--

```
forward 50 back 20
```

I want to copy "forward" in simple char array[], "50" in char array[] (each string in each char array[])

I am only able to store first element in first array.

I've tried storing index of "space" and then storing the integer values until "another space "\n" found in 2d-array, but it stored only first string (forward) in all the char arrays i ran loop on...
 Here's the code i was checking on.

```
for (int j=0; arr[1][j] != ' '; j++)
{
    check[m] = arr[1][j];
    m++;
}

check[m] = '\0';
int k = 0;
cout << check << endl;

if (arr[1][m] == ' ')
{
    for (;arr[1][m] == ' ';)
    {
        m++;

        cout << arr[1][m];
        value[k] = arr[1][m];
        k++;
    }
 }
 value[k] = '\0';
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried, i mean your code

Comment: Have you considered `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Nope.. we haven't studied in our course yet. So we are not allowed to include vectors.

Comment: I can understand `2D array of strings`, but can anyone tell me what are `strings of 2D array` ? How is it possible you have strings of 2D array?

Comment: Strings are the letters stored in the array. 
" i am commenting on stackoverflow "

So, i'm referring strings to letters separated by spaces (which user inputs)

Comment: you should have simply said you wanted to split a char-string by spaces. It is much clearer.

Comment: @AdilIqbal Can you use `stringstream`?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems as though this might should actually be a C question and not a C++ question.

But since this is homework anyway maybe seeing a C++11 solution will get you moving in the right direction.

```
const char* arr[]{"forward ", "50 ", "back ", "20"};
const string check = accumulate(cbegin(arr), cend(arr), string());
```

After this `check` will contain "forward 50 back 20".

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/IVjsO2)